# Crossing the limit cycle in a DDE

Tags: stability-theory, delay-differential-equations, limit-cycles

I have the following delay differential equation
$$
\begin{align}
    \frac{dx_1(t)}{dt} &= \frac{1}{1 + \left(\frac{x_2(t-\tau)}{p_0}\right)^n} - \mu_m \cdot x_1(t)\\
    \frac{dx_2(t)}{dt} &= x_1(t) - \mu_p \cdot x_2(t)
\end{align}
$$

When I now simulate this system and plot the phase plane it looks like a converging to a limit cycle. When I, however, set the initial conditions to be within the supposed limit cycle (yellow curve below), the limit cycle is crossed.
[image: Phase plane simulation]

How can this be? Is this now a stable limit cycle?

The simulation was achieved with the parameter set: $\tau=18.5$, $p_0=100$, $n=5$, $\mu_m=0.03$, and $\mu_p=0.03$.